# Sub-setting rows/columns in a dataframe based on Similarity in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, similarity

I have a dataframe "df" as below:

```
       V1 V2
   1   b  a
   2   b  a
   3   a  b
   4   b  a
   5   a  b
   6   a  b
   7   a  b
   8   b  a
   9   a  b
   10  a  b
   11  a  b
   12  b  a
```

Is there a way that I can **automate the following 3 steps** in R?

**Step 1:** 
R identifies that in the 12 rows of the dataframe "df" & the pattern "a b" is repeating majority of the times.

**Step2:**
Based on the majority pattern in Step 1, R subsets a dataframe with only those rows which contain the majority pattern in Step 1.

**Step3:** 
R outputs a new sub-setted dataframe of Step2.

Is there a package to do this or a function that I can build? Any guidance will be very valuable. Thank You

Comment: Yes @jogo. Done

Comment: I have corrected this, now its a dataframe

Comment: Step 3 is unclear to me. Does _R outputs a new sub-setted dataframe of Step2._ means you want to have the result written to a file or just printed?

Comment: Hi @UweBlock. I want to have the each output stored in a new dataframe each time. Also, just curious, in R is it possible to have multiple matrices/dataframes as the output of a for loop?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _each time_. Perhaps, your underlying problem is more complex than your Q?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple matrcies or dataframes as output of a function, e.g. Just combine them into a `list()`. `lapply()` which is kind of an implied `for` loop does this for you automatically. It returns a list element for each "iteration".

Comment: `for(j in 1:length(SKU)){
  
  op.fin<- subset(temp, GMID %in% SKU[j]) %>% 
    select(Group1,MonthVec,Sales) %>% 
    spread(MonthVec,Sales, fill=0) %>% 
    select(-Group1) %>% 
    as.matrix
   
} `

Comment: This is the loop, My output should be many matrices. The problem is if I store them in "op.fin" i.e. a list then, the expression for the loop requires that i put it as "op.fin[j]". However this gives an error since using "[]" with a matrix/dataframe has meaning ... Also I have used only sapply and lapply once.

Comment: Perhaps, this should be posed as a separate Q. However, you may try `lapply(seq_len(SKU), function(j), {subset(temp, GMID %in% SKU[j]) %>% 
    select(Group1, MonthVec, Sales) %>% 
    spread(MonthVec, Sales, fill = 0) %>% 
    select(-Group1) %>% 
    as.matrix()})`. This should return a list of matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your updated Q, you may try this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
cols <- c("V1", "V2")
df[, .N, by = cols][N == max(N)][, N := NULL][df, on = cols, nomatch = 0]
#   V1 V2 id
#1:  a  b  3
#2:  a  b  5
#3:  a  b  6
#4:  a  b  7
#5:  a  b  9
#6:  a  b 10
#7:  a  b 11
```

**Explanation**

1. `setDT(df)` coerces the data.frame to `data.table` without copying.
2. The relevant columns are defined to save typing.
3. The number of occurences of each combination in the relevant columns are counted.
4. Only the combination with the highest number of occurences is kept. This completes **Step 1** of the Q which asks to find the *majority pattern*.
   Note that in case of a *tie*, i.e., two or more combinations have the same maximum number of occurences, all combinations are returned. The OP hasn't specified how he wants to handle this case.
5. The counts are removed as they are no longer needed.
6. Finally, the original `df` is joined so that all rows of `df` which match the majority pattern are selected. `nomatch = 0` specifies an inner join. This completes **Step 2** and perhaps also **Step 3** (but this is unclear to me, see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642127/sub-setting-rows-columns-in-a-dataframe-based-on-similarity-in-r/42689002#comment72501646_42642127).
   Note that the row numbers in the `id` column are kept in the result without any additional effort. This would be the case for any other additional column in `df`as well.

**Data**

```
df <- fread("id    V1 V2
   1   b  a
   2   b  a
   3   a  b
   4   b  a
   5   a  b
   6   a  b
   7   a  b
   8   b  a
   9   a  b
   10  a  b
   11  a  b
   12  b  a")
# EDIT: By request of the OP, the row number (id) should be kept
# df[, id := NULL]
```

Comment: Thankkk Youu @UweBlock :)  In the output that you have I need 1 addition. I need to preserve/keep the rowname in the output table the same as of the input table. What I mean by this is: In your output I want the rowames to be the original location of each pattern instead of the chronological sequence of #1, #2, #3 ... #7

Comment: Do you mean that `id` (the row number ) should be kept? Or that the subsetted rows should be marked by using a third column?

Comment: I mean: "id (the row number ) should be kept"

Comment: Hi @UweBlock 

    
    [[32]]
    V1 V2 V3 id
    1:  a  b  c  2
    2:  a  b  c  3
    3:  a  b  b  8
    4:  c  a  b  9
    5:  c  a  b 11
    6:  c  a  b 12

    [[33]]
    V1 V2 V3 id
    1:  c  a  c  2
    2:  c  a  a  3
    3:  c  a  b  4
    4:  c  a  a  5
    5:  c  a  a  6
    6:  c  a  a  8 
    7:  c  a  a 11

Comment: @UneBlock I have a specific doubt about the above output (which i have shared in my comment just above this), its not getting arranged vertically. I want to avoid editing the question as its more in continuation with our comments, please suggest. I have read the "Learn More" in the comments section below, but the Ctrl + I for inserting an image is not working, or I may be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your point. It looks like a list of data.frames. Perhaps a result of a `lapply()`? Perhaps, It would be a good idea if you post a new question (or search SO for answers using `rbindlist`, first).

Comment: Ok. I'll take it one step at a time: Does "df[, .N, by = cols][N == max(N)][, N := NULL][df, on = cols, nomatch = 0]"     work for 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, you just have to specify the relevant columns for determining the majority pattern , e.g., `cols <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")`. Besides these columns, the data.frame may contain additional columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need duplicates of the most common combination? If not, there's a really simple way to do it with data.table

```
library("data.table")

#Create sample data, set seed to have the same output    
set.seed(1)
df <- data.table(V1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"),10 , replace = T),
                 V2 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"),10 , replace = T),
                 V3 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"),10 , replace = T))

#Subset
cols <- names(df)
df[, .N, by = cols][order(-N)][1,]
```

Output(N is number of occurences):

```
   V1 V2 V3 N
1:  b  c  b 2
```

Comment: Thank You @Alexvonrass, based on the suggestion of jogo I have rephrased the question for better clarity

Comment: for  your reply. I am aware of this, however I am specifically looking to automate the steps mentioned in the question. I apologize for rephrasing the question after you had replied with a possible solution, but did so in the best interest of the community and for more clarity on what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is "similarity" in your query - just finding the most common row and taking only that? If yes, you just need to group by all variables and sort by occurence

If you're talking about similar, but not matching text in your columns you need to look into edit distances (this package is good for the task https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf)

Comment: Thank You for your comment Alex.. .. I need R to automatically figure out, 1) which alphabet pattern is the most common among the 12 rows?: (say) "a c b" in the 3 respective columns.       2. Subset the data frame "df2" based on only those rows which have the same "a c b" sequence.          3. Output the sub-setted data frame.

Comment: Thank You @jogo I have reworded the question to make it concise.